# Loop animation with jquery

Tags: jquery, animation

I am pretty new to all this jQuery stuff and now i'm asking myself: What would be the easiest way to loop an animation. I tried `setInterval()` but it doesn't work. Also if I take the method as a callback the animation just gets kinda laggy.

I created this fiddle with the animation how it should look like, but it only animates one time.

http://jsfiddle.net/xFZnS/1/
I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: Can you put the code that causes the problem in your question. Why does adding the callback make it lag? It already looks like it is lagging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#sk1").delay(1200).animate({opacity:"0"}, 100, animationFadeIn);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xFZnS/2/)

But that is still weird animation IMO. For better performance, you should use CSS for animation.

Comment: Thanks very much! helped me a lot ... im just kinda annoyed now that it 's so simple and I was sitting here for like an hour or so and I just couldn't solve it ... (^.^)

Answer (score 0):

recursion caused by `arguments.callee()` call after last animation is your way is your way

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/glenswift/xFZnS/7/)